# How do I stabilise a delaminating pine floor?

Tags: repair, flooring, pine

We bought a flat with softwood pine floors in the living room. The area of the flooring that receives the most traffic is beginning to delaminate/flake/splinter (I'm not sure of the correct term!)

I'm aware that we could sand and refinish the entire floor but my question is: is there any way to stabilise this and prevent any further damage in this specific area (the rest of the floor is fine)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any work you do in one smaller area will end up being visible when the floor is viewed as a whole. It takes a lot of effort & skill to blend a "patched" finish into the rest of the finished floor and make it disappear, and it may not be possible at all. i.e. until you sand down the whole floor, this spot will remain visible. That may not be a concern for you for a few years, but it's something to be aware of. Also, is this an owned or rented flat?

Comment: If there's nothing that can be done specifically I guess my only recourse is to cover the affected area with a protective mat, or will that make it worse? (This is also where the previous owner had a swivel chair at a desk, so I'm assuming that's the cause of the damage) Also, it's an owned flat.

Comment: I'm not saying you _can't_ do something to refinish just this area, but that the refinished area will be visible without a well practiced, skilled professional doing the work, and even then, it may be detectable. This is just a warning of what lays ahead, not an admonition to not do the work this way. Eventually, IMO, you'll want to refinish the whole floor to even things out, _when_ you do that is up to you - your finances and tolerance for the visibility of the "patched" area will determine that.

Comment: @FreeMan Isn't floor refinishing well within the realm of a capable DIYer? Some tool rentals, lugging heavy equipment, and several hours are needed. So one could easily say to let a pro take the job over.

Comment: It is, @AdamO. However, refinishing _part_ of a floor and getting that refinished part to "disappear" so that it doesn't look refinished are two different things... Again, I'm not saying OP _must_ hire someone to do the work, just warning him that the refinished portion will, in all likelihood, be visibly apparent and that he should be prepared for that.

Comment: I have frequently finished worn or damaged patches of wood floor and while it's not good as new it's way WAY better than  before. Sometimes only I can see it.  I think the question is whether this floor is in the process of disintegrating, not whether a patch can be blended to perfection.

Comment: @FreeMan I think I agree that getting a perfectly blended spot repair is probably beyond my capabilities

Comment: @jay613 can you elaborate on "inished worn or damaged patches of wood floor". Also, "in the process of disintegrating" sounds quite severe - I assume the only remedy for that is sand + refinish?

Comment: @protiek  I have had small floor areas damaged by furniture legs, nail polish remover, and similar goofs. Your problem is different but my point above was that the discussion of whether you can refinish this to perfection is a distraction.  If you wanted that you would have posted a very different question.    Your problem is actually more interesting, those boards don't seem suitable as floor boards, I wonder if they are meant to be  sub floor.  What is underneath them?   And if you want a rustic look but not splinters and holes, what should you do with this?  It's a great question.

Answer (score 5):

Do the edges of the growth rings actually lift up if you put a fingernail under them?

- If so

  - squeeze some wood glue under there
  - push the grain back down
  - put down a sheet of waxed paper (shiny side down toward the glue)
  - cover with a board, thick cardboard, sheet of metal, whatever's handy and flat, and put some weight on top of it for a few minutes.
  - lift everything up and wipe up any glue that's squeezed out and visible (use a damp sponge or paper towel)
  - place all the materials back on top and wait a couple of hours until the glue dries.
  - This will hold the slivers down to keep them from popping off.
  - Refinish to your heart's content. <sup>*</sup>
- If not

  - It's *probably* not going to lift any more than it has.
  - Do *not* try to put wood putty in there to fill the hole, it'll only be *more* noticeable.
  - Lightly sand the whole area and carefully pick up all the sanding dust.
  - Mix the sanding dust in with some wood glue to make a thick paste.
  - Spread the paste into the voids to fill them. Allow the glue to dry.
  - The sawdust from *this* wood will make the patch nearly disappear.
  - Refinish to your heart's content.<sup>*</sup>

    - Having glue in this patch will make this stand out a bit, especially if you stain. Stain won't soak into the glued areas like it will into wood *or* wood filler.
    - More sawdust and less glue will *help* reduce the visibility of the filler under stain, but may not completely make it disappear.
    - Woodworkers use the dust/glue trick as filler all the time, but staining has, somewhat, gone out of fashion, so it's not as obvious.

---

<sup>*</sup>Note that the refinished section will probably be noticeable (different stain color and/or finish sheen than the rest of the floor) to some extent, but will be perfectly functional until *you* decide you can't stand the look anymore (or sell). The only way to completely blend in the finished repair (without years of experience) will be to completely strip & refinish the whole floor in one shot.

Comment: Good answer, I think you are too worried about the repair standing out.  It's a rustic look with exposed nails and knots.  Some evidence of carpentry and TLC will enhance it.

Comment: Fair points, @jay613. I couldn't see the images when I first posted my comments. And yes, a "rustic look" is one thing, but an uneven finish is another...

Comment: There's what looks like some wood putty already in the knot, so there's probably not much to worry about the difference of look in a repair, but it's good info for anyone else that has a similar issue and does care about a repair blending in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any chairs near this spot, it will get much worse. Especially if the floor is meant to have a varnished surface.

Just put a piece of carpet over the area.